# Multiple logout uris for one client or changing them runtime

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer4 for SSO for an multi-tenant application where tenants are specified with subdomains:

```
tenant1.app.com
tenant2.app.com
```

I want to register all of them with only one Client.

Every tenants has its own `RedirectUri` like `tenant1.app.com/oidc`, own `PostLogoutRedirectUri` and its own `FrontChannelLogoutUri` like `tenant1.app.com/account/oidc-logout`. It is possible to specify multiple `RedirectUris` and multiple `PostLogoutRedirectUris` and even to implement custom logic for validating them, but I can't find a way to specify multiple logout uris or to change them programatically.

I need to find the user's tenant and construct the logout uri for the iframe. The problem is that I don't have any access to the uris that are rendered inside the `SignOutIframe`.

Is there a way to modify the logout URI for a client other than in configuration?

Comment: I guess a place you can play with is the `IClientStore` implementation, you use in your instance. It returns a list of Clients, each has a `FrontChannelLogoutUri`. You can adjust each in runtime based on http context. But I would perform the requests routing behind the scene, keeping the visible uri constant for all the tenants.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that but just wanted to see if there's a better way because I need to use some heuristics to resolve the tenant name + the application because there will be several apps for every tenant and won't be so nice.

Comment: You can put a middleware between your client apps and Identity server 4. Middleware can accept multiple callback and post logout URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution without registering multiple clients.

You can override the `GetClientEndSessionUrlsAsync` method in the `EndSessionRequestValidator` and add your custom logic for changing the front channel and back channels urls.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a separate client per host name I think as the front-channel and back-channel logout URIs are only 1-per-client.

The alternative is to use the back channel mechanism and have a single endpoint that would work for any tenant (I don't know if that'd work in your architecture)